# an someone please explain to me what #ifdef does here?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

Can someone please explain what #ifdef..#else..#endif does in this piece of code? It's from an open-source iphone twitter client.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_OAUTH
@interface NTLNTwitterClient : NTLNOAuthHttpClient {
#else
@interface NTLNTwitterClient : NTLNHttpClient {
#endif
    int requestPage;
    NSString *screenNameForUserTimeline;
    BOOL parseResultXML;
    NSObject<NTLNTwitterClientDelegate> *delegate;
    BOOL requestForTimeline;
    BOOL requestForDirectMessage;
    NTLNTwitterXMLParser *xmlParser;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ENABLE_OAUTH is defined somewhere else, then the class NTLNTwitterClient will be a subclass of NTLNOAuthHttpClient.

If ENABLE_OAUTH is not defined, then the class NTLNTwitterClient will be a subclass of NTLNHttpClient.